# Lotus Domino 8.5.3 FP6 ignoring archive policy

Tags: ibm-domino, archive, lotus-notes

We are using Domino 8.5.3 FP6. (64bit) on Win-2008 R2 64bit.

We have a policy to archive emails older then 365 days into archive folder (for all users). 
2 years back, our server crashed dueto hardware failure. we acquired new hardware and restored the email DB's and settings from backup. all went fine.

After that we noticed that archive policy which run weekly and moves mails older then 365 days is moving many recent random emails like last days, week,month to the 'Older than 365days Archive' folder so I disabled archiving.

Today i found out that it happens with old accounts only, And Accounts which were created after that crash are working ok there archive is ok.

I have executed fixup -f -j , tried replacing the Mailfile template, Running an Updall -RX and a Compact -C. but no use.

my server is still bleeding with this bloody issue from past 2 years till date. most users inbox have crossed 15-20 Gb and above.

When ever i try to run the archive, it does not select only 365 days old. it selects random emails like one week, one month, few months also and move them to archive which creates confusion when users try to search recent email.

its getting very frustrating for me

Comment: Did you check the profile- documents in the databases? There is one `Archive Profile` and one for each setting that has the name of the setting (e.g. `Default for Last Modified`)... Please check the contents of these profiles (using notespeek or Ytria ScanEZ or any other appropriate tool) in one of the affected databases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem now seems to be ok. I change criteria of archiving TO "**not modified in 365/days**" rather than "*older than 365 days*"

Thank you :)